# MTOM message HttpRequestException C#

Tags: c#, soap, httprequest, multipart

```
        public async Task<string> SendMessage(string body, string url, string soapaction, string username, string password)
        {

            try
            {
                string boundary = "_Part_2_971447519.1690529867838";
                string contentType = "multipart/related; type=\"application/xop+xml\"; start=\"<rootpart@soapui.org>\"; start-info=\"text/xml\"; boundary=\"----="+ boundary+"\"";
                string soapEnvelope = @"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:ns=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/messaging/200908/"">        
<soapenv:Header/>        
<soapenv:Body>       
<ns:objectId>453FF904-32A1</ns:objectId>         
</soapenv:Body>    
</soapenv:Envelope>";


                string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
                Uri _endpoint = new Uri(url);
                HttpRequestMessage _requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, _endpoint);
                MultipartContent _multiPartcontent = new MultipartContent("related", boundary);
                HttpContent _xmlContent = new StringContent(soapEnvelope);
                _xmlContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/soap+xml");
                _xmlContent.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", soapaction);
                _xmlContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(contentType);
                _multiPartcontent.Add(_xmlContent);
                _requestMessage.Content = _multiPartcontent;
                
                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", credentials);


                HttpResponseMessage httpRequest = await httpClient.SendAsync(_requestMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead, CancellationToken.None);
                string responseXml = await httpRequest.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return responseXml;
                

            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return e.Message.ToString();
            }
        }
```

With this code I sending MTOM message (without file attachment). The code works fine, when the **objectId** is valid. If the **objectId**is invalid in the SOAP envelope I get the following error message:
`---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a stream.`

The server should send back SOAP envelope with detailed error message, but somehow a HttpRequestException happens.